# Problemas al validar tabla html con jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

Estoy intentando validar las celdas de una tabla html con jquery
tengo una tabla que tiene un campo llamado estado y tengo unos botones que se deben bloquear según el estado que tenga la fila en la tabla. Hice un método que funciona , pero el problema que tiene es que siempre me valida el primer registro que está en al tabla, por lo tanto aunque seleccione otro registro, el sistema me va a indicar la validación correspondiente al primer registro que muestra al tabla y la idea que se valide por fila seleccionada.

Acá imagen de mi tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá el código de jquery que utilizo
No agregué el código de la tabla ya que es mucho y esta en un servlet.

```
<script>
    function cargarEstadoReservas() {

      if($("#resultado td:nth-child(8)").html()==="PENDIENTE")
       {
        $("#btnEnviarReserva").prop( "disabled", true );
        $("#btnGuardarReserva").prop( "disabled", false );
       }
     else
       {
          if($("#resultado td:nth-child(8)").html()==="POR CONFIRMAR")
           {
              $("#btnEnviarReserva").prop( "disabled", false );
              $("#btnGuardarReserva").prop( "disabled", false );
           }
         else
           {
              if($("#resultado td:nth-child(8)").html()==="CONFIRMADA")
              {
                 $("#btnEnviarReserva").prop( "disabled", true );
                 $("#btnGuardarReserva").prop( "disabled", true );
              }
            else
              {
                 if($("#resultado td:nth-child(8)").html()==="CANCELADA")
                  {
                    $("#btnEnviarReserva").prop( "disabled", true );
                    $("#btnGuardarReserva").prop( "disabled", true );
                  }
              }
          }
       }
    }
```

Si se fijan en al validación , este método bloquea los botones de un modal de acuerdo al estado de un registro de una tabla y cada vez que selecciono un registro de la tabla 
si el estado es PENDIENTE , se bloquea uno de 2 botones
si el estado es POR CONFIRMAR ,se bloquea uno de 2 botones
Si el estado es CONFIRMARA ,se bloquea ambos botones
Si el estado es CANCELADA ,se bloquea ambos botones

Pero sólo me valida la primera fila , es decir bloquea sólo un botón , aunque yo seleccione otro registro con otro estado.Por lo tanto sólo me bloquea los botones en el modal de acuerdo al primer registro.
Quisiera saber que le falta a la función para que recorra toda la tabla y así muestre de acuerdo al registro seleccionado ?.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que siempre buscas el octavo `td` en toda la tabla.  Por eso siempre te va a dar el mismo resultado.  Necesitas pasar el boton que fue presionado a la funcion para usar el contexto correcto.  Algo asi:

```
function cargarEstadoReservas(boton) {
  var tr = $(boton).parent('tr');

  if(tr.find("td:nth-child(8)").html()==="PENDIENTE")
   {
    $("#btnEnviarReserva").prop( "disabled", true );
    $("#btnGuardarReserva").prop( "disabled", false );
   }
 else
   {
      if(tr.find("td:nth-child(8)").html()==="POR CONFIRMAR")
       {
          $("#btnEnviarReserva").prop( "disabled", false );
          $("#btnGuardarReserva").prop( "disabled", false );
       }
     else
       {
          if(tr.find("td:nth-child(8)").html()==="CONFIRMADA")
          {
             $("#btnEnviarReserva").prop( "disabled", true );
             $("#btnGuardarReserva").prop( "disabled", true );
          }
        else
          {
             if(tr.find("td:nth-child(8)").html()==="CANCELADA")
              {
                $("#btnEnviarReserva").prop( "disabled", true );
                $("#btnGuardarReserva").prop( "disabled", true );
              }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: hola, no me funcionó, sera porque en el botón de la tabla que abre el modal no le pase el parámetro botón? así tengo la llamada al método desde el botón onclick="cargarEstadoReservas()"

Comment: tienes que cambiarlo a esto: `onclick="cargarEstadoReservas(this)"`

Answer (score 0):

Debes cargar el modal con javascript usando el atributo `onclick` para llamar la funcion que permitirá 'settear' o cambiar el comportamiento de los botones según cada fila seleccionada, para eso lee la documentación de [modal bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#modalshow).

Agrego un ejemplo.

```js
function editar(element){
  $('#editarModal').modal('show')
  
  // busco el padre de element.
  let eltr = $(element).parent().parent();
  // busco el estado (un td la clases reserva_estado)
  let eltd = $(eltr).find('.reserva_estado')[0]
  // busco el valor del estado.
  let elestado = $(eltd).attr('data-estado')  
  
  // cambiar el estado del botton
  if(elestado === 'editar'){
    $('#editar').removeAttr('disabled')
  }else{
    $('#editar').attr('disabled','disabled')
  }
  
}
```

```html
<head>
<!-- AGREGO LA  LIBRERIA BOOTSTRAP -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<head>


<body>
<!-- LA TABLA -->
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <th>ESTADO</th>
    <th>ACCION</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="reserva">
      <td class="reserva_estado" data-estado="editar">EDITAR</td>
      <td class="reserva_accion">
        <!-- BOTON METODO ONCLICK -->
        <a onclick="editar(this)" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</a>       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="reserva">
      <td class="reserva_estado" data-estado="noeditar">NO EDITAR</td>
      <td class="reserva_accion">
        <!-- BOTON METODO ONCLICK -->
        <a onclick="editar(this)" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</a>       </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- EL MODAL-->
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="editarModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
        <button type="button" id="editar" disabled>Editar</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<body>
```

Comment: hola buenas intenté usando tu ejemplo pero no me funcionó, será porque tengo la tabla con los datos dentro de un servlet?